# Set ID as JavaScript var

Tags: javascript, var

This is probably very simple but isn't working for me.

I need to reference and ID several times in my script, so want to use a var for the ID, in case I need to change the ID at a later date.

My code is

```
var dataID= '#dataID';
var inputData  =  $('dataID td:nth-child(12)').text();
```

The aim is to get the data from a specific cell of a data row, and then use that data in a chart, which is achieved with the second line of code.

When I specify the ID in the second line, it works, but when I try to use a var for the ID, it doesn't.

The chart has lots of data displayed, so I don't want to have to specify the ID of the table in every line of code for inputting the data into the chart, hence the need to set the ID using a var.

Hope that makes sense.

The code has been simplified to the issue at hand. If the fuller function is helpful can post.

Many thanks

Richard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close. JavaScript won't interpolate variables in strings (like PHP does, for instance), so you need to concatenate.

```
var dataID= '#dataID';
var inputData  =  $(dataID + ' td:nth-child(12)').text();
```

With the new ES6 string interpolation syntax (which is supported in Chrome and Firefox already):

```
var dataID= '#dataID';
var inputData  =  $(`${dataID} td:nth-child(12)`).text();
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. It is working as I need with one very annoying adaptation. for some reason there needs to be a space between the ' and the td:nth.. so it reads: ' td:nth-child(12)'. This was required for my specific implementation but wasn't for the basic testing I did, so some people may want to try the space in here if their example isn't working.

Comment: @RichardHarris You're right! Thanks for that! I fixed my answer, it now contains the space.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [the Addition operator (`+`)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.6.1) to concatenate your string variable with the string literal.

```js
var dataID = 'dataID';
var inputData = $('#' + CSS.escape(dataID) + ' td:nth-child(12)').text();
```

Using [`CSS.escape`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS.escape) may be a good idea in case your variable is not a valid identifier. It's still not widely implemented, but can be [polyfilled](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/CSS.escape/blob/master/css.escape.js).

Comment: I could not get this method to work in my specific implementation, though it may be a solution. I have not had time yet to look into the css.escape as i'm short on time but looks like a similarly suitable solution to the one above. Thanks

Comment: @RichardHarris In this case it doesn't matter: `CSS.escape('dataID') === 'dataID'`. But it may be useful if `dataID` can be something like `'3:>#)'`, which should be escaped as `'\33 \:\>\#\)'`

Comment: Ah ok, that is useful then. I might have a use for that a bit later. Thanks